# Strange hair-looking thing appears in object mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was sculpting a model and when I was done I noticed that there's something strange looking like a hair. At first, I thought it was just an edge and switched to edit mode to erase it. But it disappeared when I switched to edit mode. Does anybody knows to erase it?[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you hide and unhide the model to confirm it isn't part of another object? Are there any modifiers on the object? Are you using shapekeys?

Comment: There are 6 modifiers: Armature, Two ParticleSystems, Two SurfaceDeforms, Subdivision

Comment: If you disable all of them, is the artefact still there? If no, which modifier is responsible for the problem?

Comment: Artefact is still there. nothing happened

Comment: We probably need your file to inspect it. If it disappears in _Edit Mode_ it usually has to be something caused by a modifier. But when you say disabling them does not help, we can only make wild guesses without the file. The thing is, it does not show the orange selection outline while the rest is selected... that's strange if it is part of that object.